# Passwordless openssh connection between 2 windows machine

Tags: windows, openssh

I have successfully established passwordless openssh connection betwen windows and linux m/c.
Similarly i have setup connection between windows and unix m/c.

Just wanted to know **Is passwordless openssh connection from Windows to Windows m/c possible???**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes in exactly the same way. I use openssh through cygwin and it works no problems. The same setup with the .ssh directory is supported

Both machines would need openssh installed

Comment: See currently we are following the below procedure:1.Installing Openssh on both machines(If i am not wrong Cygwin also comes with openssh) 2.Generating public key with command ssh-keygen -t rsa   3.Adding that public key into the authorized keys of target machine(Here we are creating authorized_keys file in the user profile like in C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\home\username 4. trying to ssh to target machine with command ssh user@hostname after this we are getting error of connection closed by [IP of target machine]. Can you guess what can be the issue.We are struggling with it from last few weeks

Comment: Whats in the windows event viewer ?

Comment: I have not used windows event viewer before.I googled and again tried to connect to other machine i didnt got any error message related to openssh but info messages are there

Comment: Event Type: Information
Event Source: OpenSSHd
Event Category: None
Event ID: 0
Date:  7/12/2013
Time:  4:57:55 PM
User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer: INPUSCPC05754
Description:
The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( OpenSSHd ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer.You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description;see Help and Support for details.The following information is part of the event: OpenSSHd:PID 512:`OpenSSHd' service stopped,exit status: 255.

Comment: IF it is possible for you can you please tell me how you have achieved it? and what are all the possibilities of failure? plz

Comment: I use cygwin for it. Ive never used openssh stand alone. are the permissions set correct ?

Comment: permission sets are correct i think so. and i am also having admin rights.Can you just once tell me how you are doing this? it will be very much helpful for me.

Comment: I have cygwin set up and cygserver is set as a service. in my cygwin/home/user dir it has the .ssh folder the same as linux. cygserver. I ran mkpasswd and mkgroup to make the users. I can then just connect as usual ]#

Comment: Be careful with path variables, You may have a clash with cgywin1.dll

Comment: can you please tell me "cygserver is set as a service" how to do this?

Comment: run cygserver-config it will ask if you want to install as a service

Comment: i have new question related to jsch windows server posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945960/jsch-execute-command-on-windows-machine-and-take-the-output please help me if you are aware of this issue.