# JSCH execute command on windows machine and take the output

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Here i am executing command on remote windows server from my local windows machine with below code . But i am getting error as

> "Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to
>   Execute process."

can anybody help me here to come out of this problem?

```
 String user = username;
            String pass = password;
            String host = ip;
JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
 java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);

            session.setPassword(pass);
            session.connect();



            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.connect();
 ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cmd.exe /c \"echo %cd%\"");
 InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channel.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
            String jarOutput;
 System.out.println("1");

            while ((jarOutput = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("Inside while loop");
                System.out.println(jarOutput + "\n");

            }

            System.out.println("2");
            reader.close();
```

Comment: You just have to move the `connect()` method after the `setCommand()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install cygwin on the host (String **host** = ip) windows to use jsch.
Follow this site: https://dbaportal.eu/2015/03/05/installing-openssh-cygwin-1-7-35-on-windows-2012-r2/